# Initialising struct in c

Tags: c, struct

In C we cannot assign `int variable = true;`, where as the below code executes.

```
typedef struct mystruct {
    int variable;
} mystruct_;

int main(void){
    // Your code here!
    mystruct_ st = {true};
    printf("%i",st.variable);
}
```

Why true isn't valid value for `int variable = true`, but is valid for an `int` member in a struct?
Can someone please explain why?

Comment: This is [structure initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization).

Comment: @AdrianMole, This is not his question.

Comment: Unclear what you mean?  "Why?" because the C-standard understands that, and it is valid syntax.

Comment: "In C we cannot assign `int variable = true;`" Are you sure of that?

Comment: @Mat OP means you can't do that inside the `struct` declaration, I think.

Comment: @Youssef13 I think it is: `mystruct_ st = {true};` is structure initialization, as described in the link I gave.

Comment: @Adrian Mole: that's a possibility indeed. Zac please clarify your question by [edit]ing it, showing the code that doesn't work. [mcve]

Comment: @AdrianMole, Yes, it's structure initialization. But his confusion isn't with that syntax. It's because he think that `int variable = true` is invalid, where as true is valid when the structure contains `int`.

Comment: `int variable = true;` did not work in an online editor when I tried, however I believe it was due to the missing stdbool.h import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In C we cannot assign `int variable = true;`

This is not correct. It compiles and run successfully. The following code compiles and runs perfectly on GCC.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct mystruct {
    int variable;
} mystruct_;

int main(void){
    int variable = true;
    mystruct_ st = {true};
    printf("%i %i",st.variable, variable);
}
```

By the way, the `stdbool.h` contains the following:

```c
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

That's why it should work with `int`.

Comment: This is correct. I got an error due to a missing stdbool.h import and got confused.

Comment: Pedantic note: `stdbool.h` was introduced in `C99`, for those to whom it matters.